# 2D boolean array, check if array contains a false

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm using a 2D array of booleans in C#. I've looked up the Array.Exists function at [dot net pearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-exists) but I can't get it to work, either because I'm using booleans or because it's a 2D array.

```
bool[,] array = new bool[4, 4];

if (array.Contains(false)) {}; // This line is pseudo coded to show what I'm looking for
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know if this is the proper way or not but casting each element seems to work:

```
bool[,] a = new bool[4,4]
    {
        {true, true, true, true},
        {true, true, false, true},
        {true, true, true, true},
        {true, true, true, true},
    };

    if(a.Cast<bool>().Contains(false))
    {
        Console.Write("Contains false");
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if (!a.Cast<bool>().All(b => b))
```

Comment: `bool[*,*]` does not contain a definition for `Any` and no extension method `Any` accepting a first argument of type `bool[*,*]` could be found.

Comment: `bool[*,*]` does not contain a definition for `All` and no extension method `All` accepting a first argument of type `bool[*,*]` could be found.

Comment: Make sure you have `using System.Linq` at the top of the file

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn This only works on one dimensional arrays.

Comment: Should be better now.

Answer (score 3):

```
var control = array.OfType<bool>().Contains(false);
```

You can always use [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method when you working with `multidimensional` arrays.It's very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ's (`using System.Linq;`) `OfType` or `Cast` array extensions allows you to test if each array element is true, and if not can be used to fire your event.

```
a[0,0] = false; //Change this to test
if (!a.OfType<bool>().All(x => x))
{
     Console.Write("Contains A False Value");
     //Do Stuff
}
else
{
     Console.Write("Contains All True Values");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:
`if (array.ToList().Contains(false))`

Generally speaking if efficiency is not that needed then converting to list is very useful